# How to implement pass-through authentication in Rails 3 on Oracle DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, authentication, activerecord

I am currently evaluating using Rails in the enterprise. The first roadblock I have discovered in our environment is the pass-through authentication. All of our business security roles and permissions are stored in the DB level for obvious reasons e.g. DB can be accessed from multiple platforms.

I read an article about this in OTN: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fernandez-rails-connections-101759.html

As this was written about 4 years ago, is there a new way to resolve this type of authentication in Rails, or is it still an issue?

Comment: Do you want just to authenticate users with Oracle DB user/password (but Rails could use always one common DB user to establish database session) or do you need also that database session is established using individual user/password for each user?

Comment: The second way. I want to create a user DB session on the fly for each user with its username/password to execute the queries depending on the users' permissions.

Comment: Hi Ray, any recommendations? Thanks